# Oracle View Creation with a Database generated ID from a Sequence Object

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design

Can i create an oracle "View" with a DB generated Primary Key?

I want to create a view with its ID being a DB generated ID from a Sequence object.

Comment: a VIEW is just a sql statement - do you want to persist the same ID each time you run a query against the view? if so - then you need to store this value in a table first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do exactly that, but you can do something like this:

```
select rownum, field1, field2
  from...
```

the rownum is an aoutogenerated field that holds exactly that, but it's assigned BEFORE ordering records, so if you have an ORDER BY clause, then you'll have to do this:

```
Select rownum, *
  from (select ....
         order by ....)
```

Comment: As Randy already mentioned, you would need to persist the IDs in a table if you want an item to always have the same ID.  This will simply assign numbers on the fly based on the current contents of the database.  To compare it to a primary key is very misleading.

Comment: I ran into the need of this because i am using Hibernate as my ORM and Hibernate needs an ID (Primary Key) for any entity, in this case the entity being the view.

Comment: @mandy - But the key would have to be persistent, right?  And the key would be used to do things like `UPDATE` rows in the view.  Generating the key in the view defeats both of these purposes.

Comment: Let me check more. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: @mandy I didn't understand you needed a DB Id, I thought you wanted an "autonumeric" field for the view... Your view should be returning the actual ids then, as stored on the original table.

Comment: Thats right, i need my view to return an autonumeric id. I am going to try to get that from a sequence object as @AlejoBrz has suggested. This id is not needed for any updates to the table, so i think it might work.

Comment: I tried what @AlejoBrz suggested and it worked as i needed it. Thanks a lot for suggestions and responses.