# Building an Oracle view with a sequence

Tags: oracle, sequence

I'm trying to build a new Oracle view off of a table. The only difference between the two is that I want to add a new column with a unique ID. The IDs have to be unique, but does not need to be ordered.

I tried to run a script like this:

```
CREATE VIEW <VIEW_NAME>
(
ID, VALUE1, VALUE2,...
)
AS
   SELECT SEQ1.NEXTVAL, VAL1, VAL2,... FROM <TABLE>
```

However, I'm running into errors. [A previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778323/oracle-view-creation-with-a-database-generated-id-from-a-sequence-object) mentions it's not really possible but didn't elaborate so I was hoping to get some clarity. Doing an INSERT doesn't seem useful because I'd have to populate all the other values too, at least from what I've been reading.

Edit: IDs should be consistent every time I look at the view.

Picture of error:

[image]

Comment: Do the IDs have to be consistent for each item every time you look at the view?

Comment: A view is just a stored query. Are you expecting the ID value for each row in the base table to stay the same, or is it fine for it to potentially be different every time you query the view (or at least when data is added/removed)? If you filter against the views are you expecting the IDs to be contiguous, or somehow honour the excluded rows?

Comment: If you don't mind to get different IDs every time you query de view, you can create a function that returns the nextval of the sequence (https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/2872-oracle-ora-02287-sequence-number-not-allowed-here). Using sequences directly inside a view is not allowed.

Comment: looks like your intended view would just get the next numbers... so ROWNUM seems like a good fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want a unique value for each row then you can use `ROWNUM` or the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```sql
CREATE VIEW view_name ( ID, VALUE1, VALUE2,... ) AS
   SELECT ROWNUM,
          VAL1,
          VAL2,
          ...
   FROM   table_name
```

or

```sql
CREATE VIEW view_name ( ID, VALUE1, VALUE2,... ) AS
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY val1, val2 ),
          VAL1,
          VAL2,
          ...
   FROM   table_name
```

---

> IDs should be consistent every time I look at the view.

I do not think this is possible; you would need to store the IDs somewhere and that requires a table rather than a view/sequence.

For example:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( val1, val2 ) AS
  SELECT 1, 'a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'b' FROM DUAL

CREATE SEQUENCE view_name__seq;

CREATE FUNCTION seq_value RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN view_name__seq.NEXTVAL;
END;
/

CREATE VIEW view_name ( id, value1, value2 ) AS
  SELECT seq_value, val1, val2 FROM table_name;
```

If you select from the view then first time:

```sql
SELECT * FROM view_name;
```

you get:

> ```
> ID | VALUE1 | VALUE2
> -: | -----: | :-----
>  1 |      1 | a     
>  2 |      2 | b
> ```

and second time you get:

> ```
> ID | VALUE1 | VALUE2
> -: | -----: | :-----
>  3 |      1 | a     
>  4 |      2 | b
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5609d5d7d5e17de2bf89bcdea218bc85)*

and the IDs are not consistent.

Comment: Wait why won't ROWNUM work for making IDs again? I just made it and it looks fine. Numbering of rows don't change as I re-run the script

Comment: @Yaga [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ebb1ef19b26f7f287d5a1fd87b4cbd48) Try deleting a row  and you will find that the IDs are not consistent between the rows before deletion and afterwards. There are other things, such as having row movement enabled, that can affect the order in which Oracle reads the rows and subsequently assigns `ROWNUM` values that do not require the data to change (only internally changing where in the data files it is stored).

Comment: Decided to go with the ROWNUM method. The rows will likely not get deleted, but something we will be watching out for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use INVISIBLE column in your base table.

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD MY_UNIQUE_ID NUMBER INVISIBLE;
```

Now, assign sequential number to it or use as `GENERATED AS IDENTITY` (try this)

This will not break you application and you can use it in your view to achieve the desired result and return consistent values in your view.

Cheers!!